# jpa NamedQuery with to_timestamp not working

Tags: oracle, jpa, eclipselink, toplink, named-query

first of all thanks for helping me and sorry for my inglish.

I'm having a problem when I try to execute this query, in the table all the columns are varchars2 and I need to compare them as they where timestamps.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
    c 
FROM 
    CustodiaTable c 
WHERE 
    c.ctrPro = :ctrPro 
    and TO_TIMESTAMP (c.fecInicio,'DD/MM/YYYY/HH24:MI:SS.FF') >= TO_TIMESTAMP (:fecInicio,'DD/MM/YYYY/HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

fecInicio is a `varchar2`.

one solution that I have found is doing it with native query but I need all his sons too.

thanks.

Comment: TO_TIMESTAMP is not a JQL valid function, what is your JPA provider, and what is your database?

Comment: my database is oracle11g and im using toplink.

Answer (score 0):

EclipseLink is the JPA provider ofr TopLink, and  has support for FUNC and FUNCTION described here:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/Support_for_Native_Database_Functions#FUNC

this can allow you to specify native functions such as to_timestamp in JPQL.  You should also be able to use native SQL to return object and their references, using
em.createNativeQuery(sqlString, CstodiaTable.class).getResultList();